# Starting openssh-sftp-server after installing with ipkg

Tags: sftp, ipkg

The end goal is to mount a remote director via sshfs. A [remote host (router)](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_T-Mobile_Cellspot#Entware_Installation) has the following packages installed:

```
user@remothostE8:/tmp/home/root# ipkg list_installed
asuslighttpd - 3.1.0.102 - 
bzip2 - 1.0.6-1 - 
downloadmaster - 3.1.0.104 - Download tools
expat - 2.0.1-1 - XML Parser library
ipkg-opt - 0.99.163-10 - The Itsy Package Manager
libevent - 2.0.20-1 - libevent to implement an event loop
libpar2 - 0.2-6 - A library for performing common tasks related to PAR recovery sets
libsigc++ - 2.2.3-1 - libsigc++ implements a typesafe callback system for standard C++.
libstdc++ - 6.0.2-6 - Standard C++ library, needed for dynamically linked C++ programs
libxml2 - 2.7.8-1 - Libxml2 is the XML C parser and toolkit developed for the Gnome project.
ncurses - 5.7-3 - NCurses libraries
openssh-sftp-server - 5.9p1-1 - sftp-server only from a FREE version of the SSH protocol suite of network connectivity tools.
openssl - 0.9.8v-2 - Openssl provides the ssl implementation in libraries libcrypto and libssl, and is needed by many other applications and librari
pcre - 8.31-1 - Perl-compatible regular expression library
readline - 6.1-2 - The GNU Readline library provides a set of functions for use by applications that allow users to edit command lines as they are
spawn-fcgi - 1.6.3-1 - spawn-fcgi is used to spawn fastcgi applications
uclibc-opt - 0.9.28-1 - micro C library for embedded Linux systems
wxbase - 2.8.12-1 - wxbase is a basic (non-windows) part of wxWidget toolkit
zlib - 1.2.5-1 - zlib is a library implementing the 'deflate' compression system.
```

sftp installation:

```
ipkg install openssh-sftp-server
```

No processes are returned:

```
ps | grep -i sftp
```

**How does one start the openssh-sftp-server remotely via CLI (command line)?**

I was expecting these processes to be returned:

```
1866 user     1416 S    sh -c /opt/libexec/sftp-server
1867 user     2672 S    /opt/libexec/sftp-server
```

The above responses are from the same model router at a different worksite, that meets the sshfs objective

Comment: Are you expecting to see `sftp-server` running all of the time? It only runs when a client connects and requests SFTP. It might not even run then--the SSH server can be set to handle SFTP internally, without invoking sftp-server.

Comment: @Kenster Good question.  yes: goal is to configure sftp-server always available  (device is a router).   Is my understanding incorrect?  I believe that a process has to be running to accept SFTP requests.